# Tait Bryan Rotation with Fixed Camera

Tags: python, camera

I basically need to rotate a person's head with a fixed camera view, in which [Tait Bryan Rotation](https://www.wikidoc.org/index.php/Tait-Bryan_rotations) (sometimes, Roll/Pitch/Yaw,) is applied.

However, there seems to be no python scripts for automating that process...

Any recommendations or advices in doing this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't know of any existing script to do this, but Tait-Byran rotation can be composed as three consecutive Euler rotations, X, followed by Y, followed by Z, so it should be straightforward to write such code.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any script I could take reference to understand how to make video/screenshots of an object for every rotation..?